# php How to increment number in a link end and automatically input sql from .txt file

Tags: php

php How to increment number in a link end and automatically input sql from .txt file

every page load another file link load

many .txt file continent in upload folder like this:
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

and i try to input text from txt file into automatically

```
    <?php
    // TXT link Number
    $start_file = 1;
$limit = 100;
for ($i = $start_file; $i <= 100; $i++):
    $file = "upload/{$i}.txt";
endfor;

    // PUT TXT FILE
    // File Exists
if (file_exists($file)) {
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/CITATION:/", $current)) {

    function getMatches($pattern, $subject) {
    $matches = array();

    if (is_array($pattern)) {
        foreach ($pattern as $p) {
            $m = getMatches($p, $subject);

            foreach ($m as $key => $match) {
                if (isset($matches[$key])) {
                    $matches[$key] = array_merge($matches[$key], $m[$key]);    
                } else {
                    $matches[$key] = $m[$key];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    }

    return $matches;
}
// Patterns
$patterns = array(
    '#PETITIONER:(.*?)RESPONDENT:#is',
    '#RESPONDENT:(.*?)DATE OF JUDGMENT:#is',
    '#DATE OF JUDGMENT:(.*?)BENCH:#is',
    '#BENCH:(.*?)CITATION:#is',
    '#CITATION:(.*?):#is'
);
// PUT PHP SCRIPT
$file = "/upload/{$i}.txt";
// Open the file to get existing content
$current_ex = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL, 0, 1200); 
$matches = getMatches($patterns, $current);
$current_full = file_get_contents($file);

// pubdate
$var = $matches[1]['2'];
$pj_sc_date =  date("F j, Y", strtotime($var) );
$pj_sc_pubdate =  date("y-m-d", strtotime($var) );
// Title
$titleString = "{$matches[1]['0']}{$matches[1]['1']} On {$pj_sc_date}"; 
$ucTitleString = ucwords(strtolower($titleString));
$pj_sc_title = $ucTitleString;
// Bench
$pj_sc_bench = $matches[1]['3'];
// url
$pj_sc_txt_url="http://example/upload/txt.php?filename={$i}";
// Citation
$pj_sc_citation = $matches[1]['4'];

// HTML
echo "<blockquote style='display:none'>";
print_r($matches); // result is below'
echo "</blockquote>";
echo "<div>";
echo "TITLE: ".$pj_sc_title;
echo "</div>";
echo "<div>";
echo "LINK: ".$pj_sc_txt_url;
echo "</div>";
echo "<div>";
echo "BENCH: ".$pj_sc_bench;
echo "</div>";
echo "<div>";
echo "CITATION: ".$pj_sc_citation;
echo "</div>";
echo "<time style='float: right;'>";
echo "DATE OF JUDGMENT: ".$pj_sc_date;
echo "</time>";
echo "<textarea style='width:100%; height:100%'>";
echo $current_full;
echo "</textarea>";

// DB Input
if(isset($pj_sc_title)) { 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "db";
$password = "ps";
$dbname = "db1";

// PJ mFeed
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO feed (title, link, pubdate, description, filenumber, citation, petitioner, respondent, bench, createdate, dlnote) 
    VALUES (:title, :link, :pubdate, :description, :filenumber, :citation, :petitioner, :respondent, :bench, :createdate, :dlnote)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':link', $link);
$stmt->bindParam(':pubdate', $pubdate);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':filenumber', $filenumber);
$stmt->bindParam(':citation', $citation);
$stmt->bindParam(':petitioner', $petitioner);
$stmt->bindParam(':respondent', $respondent);
$stmt->bindParam(':bench', $bench);
$stmt->bindParam(':createdate', $createdate);
$stmt->bindParam(':dlnote', $dlnote);

// insert a row
$title = $pj_sc_title;
$link = $pj_sc_txt_url;
$pubdate = $pj_sc_pubdate;
$description = $current_full;
$filenumber = $i;
$citation = $pj_sc_citation;
$petitioner = $matches[1]['0'];
$respondent = $matches[1]['1'];
$bench = $pj_sc_bench;
$createdate = $db->now();
$dlnote = 'CITATION:';
$stmt->execute();

    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;


} else {
echo 'Title was not found.';     
} 
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please format the question and clarify it somewhat?

Comment: please minimize your code example, so that it just shows what you are asking for.

Comment: all code pleas fix it

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code is what you need, reading all SQL text files inside folder ***[upload]***

```
<?php
    $start_file = 1;
    $limit = 100;
    for ($i = $start_file; $i <= 100; $i++):
        $file = "upload/{$i}.txt";
    endfor;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this script count total number of file in the upload file but i want to number incriminate automatically $i = 0 < 100 ; in every page reloaded. Thank You         Anh Pham

Comment: how to input sql in $value